# Как вывести значения в TextBox в режиме реального времени?

Tags: c#, winforms, циклы, textbox

Всем привет! Как вывести значения с метода `PrintInfo()` в форму?

Я получаю эти значения, но хочу видеть их в приложении в режиме реального времени. Они не отображаются пока работает цикл do-wile в методе `StartBrowser`.

Иными словами с сайта я получаю значение к примеру таймера каждые две секунды и хочу сразу его видеть на своей форму в TextBox'e.

Заранее спасибо за потраченное на меня время.

```
  namespace ParserFavorit
    {
        public partial class Favorit : Form
        {
            public Favorit()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void bStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string ID = tbGetID.Text;
                Second.StartBrowser(Second.GetDriver(), ID, this);
            }

            public void PrintInfo(string Command1Name, string Command2Name, string Command1Goals, string Command2Goals, string TimeOfGame, int TotalGoals)
            {
                string TimeGame = TimeOfGame;
                tbCommandName1.Text = Command1Name;
                tbCommandName2.Text = Command2Name;
                tbGetID.Text = "Time game: " + TimeGame;
                tbCommand1Goals.Text = Command1Goals;
                tbCommand2Goals.Text = Command2Goals;
                tbTotalGoals.Text = Convert.ToString(TotalGoals);
            }
        }
        public class Second
        {
            private static ChromeDriver driver = null;
            public static ChromeDriver GetDriver()
            {
                if (driver == null)
                {
                    driver = new ChromeDriver();
                }
                return driver;
            }
            public static void StartBrowser(ChromeDriver driver, string ID, Favorit MainForm)
            {
                string Time;
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("myURL" + ID);
                do
                    Time = GetInfo(MainForm);
                while (Time != "90:00");
            }

            public static string GetInfo(Favorit MainForm)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                string CommandName1 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='react-root']/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/header/div[2]/span[1]")).Text;
                string CommandName2 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='react-root']/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/header/div[2]/span[2]")).GetAttribute("innerHTML");
                string Command1Goals = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='react-root']/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/header/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]")).GetAttribute("innerHTML");
                string Command2Goals = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='react-root']/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/header/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]")).GetAttribute("innerHTML");
                string TimeOfGame = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("html/body/div/div/div//div/div[@class='headroom-wrapper']/div//div[3]/div")).GetAttribute("innerHTML");//timer eeeeeeeee
                int TotalGoals = Convert.ToInt32(Command1Goals) + Convert.ToInt32(Command2Goals);
                MainForm.PrintInfo(CommandName1, CommandName2, Command1Goals, Command2Goals, TimeOfGame, TotalGoals);
                return TimeOfGame;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Разобрался
this.Update();